# how to implement border getting lighter as radius increases?

Tags: html, css

I want to implement this kind of thing with CSS basically the border around each skill. any idea how can i achieve it?

[image: img link]

Comment: use pseudo elements i.e. `::after` or `::before`.

Comment: or dont use a border, use a box-shadow...

Answer (score -4):

```
you can check this pen:-
```

[Check This](https://codepen.io/tiberiur/pen/MwGvzz)

```
<style>
div
   width: 50px
   height: 50px
   background: red
   margin: 50px
   border-radius: 100%
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px white
   border: 1px solid red
</style>



<div></div>
```